# How to solve the Laplacian Scheme in OpenFOAM with undefined parameters

Tags: openfoam, laplacian

I have a script for fvSchemes file and the fvSchemes and fvsolutions files have defined all the solvers.

This is my fvSchemes file.

```
FoamFile
{
version 2.0;
format ascii;
class dictionary;
location "system/fin";
object fvSchemes;
}
// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //

ddtSchemes
{
default steadyState;
}

gradSchemes
{
default Gauss linear;
}

divSchemes
{
default none;
}

laplacianSchemes
{
default none;
laplacian(alpha,e) Gauss linear corrected;
}

interpolationSchemes
{
default linear;
}

snGradSchemes
{
default corrected;
}
```

// ****************

and this is my fvsolution file.

```
FoamFile
{
version 2.0;
format ascii;
class dictionary;
location "system/fin";
object fvSolution;
}
// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //

solvers
{
"e.*"
{
solver GAMG;
smoother symGaussSeidel;
tolerance 1e-6;
relTol 0.1;
}

// eFinal
//{
// $e;
// tolerance 1e-06;
// relTol 0;
//}

"alpha.*"
{
solver GAMG;
smoother symGaussSeidel;
tolerance 1e-6;
relTol 0.1;
}


}

PIMPLE
{
nNonOrthogonalCorrectors 0;
}

relaxationFactors
{
equations
{
e 0.7;
alpha 0.7;
}
}
```

// ************************************************** *********************** //

However, when I run my program using chtMultiRegionFoam solver, always there is an error and the error can be described as follows.
Solving for solid region fin

--> FOAM FATAL IO ERROR:
keyword laplacian(alphae,e) is undefined in dictionary "/home/thamasha/OpenFOAM/thamasha-10/run/tutorials/incompressible/icoFoam/engine/system/fin/fvSchemes/laplacianSchemes"

file: /home/thamasha/OpenFOAM/thamasha-10/run/tutorials/incompressible/icoFoam/engine/system/fin/fvSchemes/laplacianSchemes from line 35 to line 36.

From function const Foam::entry& Foam::dictionary::lookupEntry(const Foam::word&, bool, bool) const
in file db/dictionary/dictionary.C at line 831.

FOAM exiting

I tried to change the key word alpha to alphae too. however, when I did like that way the terminal crashed. I checked all my boundary conditions in both fin and air too. But still struggling with the error. Therefore, could you please help me to solve this.Is that the error with memory?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `laplacianSchemes` in the file `fvSchemes` as follows:

```
laplacianSchemes
{
    default Gauss linear corrected;
}
```